# Loader won't load large images

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have some pretty large PNG images stored in a database (example 1000x15000 px, 4.5MB). I am trying to load this using the Loader class...the problem I am having is when I call load(), nothing happens. No events, no errors.

I can take the same image and embed it. As long as as I set the height to less than 8000px it works fine. If I convert the embedded image to a ByteArray and try to load it, nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you storing images in a database? Let alone large images. And to answer your question the image is to large flash will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like there wasn't any way around the Flash limitation. What I ended up doing was coding up a very simple servlet which serves up the image, and then displaying the image in an HTML component.

Answer (score 4):

> In AIR 1.5 and Flash Player 10, the
>   maximum size for a BitmapData object
>   is 8,191 pixels in width or height,
>   and the total number of pixels cannot
>   exceed 16,777,215 pixels. (So, if a
>   BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels
>   wide, it can only be 2,048 pixels
>   high.) In Flash Player 9 and earlier
>   and AIR 1.1 and earlier, the
>   limitation is 2,880 pixels in height
>   and 2,880 in width.

source:  [flash.display.BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html)

Comment: Right, so is there any way to load it all in flash? I don't need it full size, even if I could show it at half size it would be great, but the problem is I can't even load it at all to scale it down.

Comment: an image asset of 15,000 pixels in width is a bit ridiculous.  i assume you're trying to handle photographs with high print resolution, perhaps to show a preview?  if automation isn't required than your best bet is to round-trip with photoshop and make your own thumbnails manually, otherwise the only other thing i can think of is load the content of your image asset into a ByteArray then create a smaller bitmap object representing the large image asset using some thumbnail algorithm.